# CSS Error in auraErrorBox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I'm suddenly getting a weird error, apparently having nothing to do with any of my new code (I undid all my code changes and the error persists).

```
<div class id="auraErrorMask">
    <div class="auraErrorBox" id="auraError">
        <span>
            <a class="close" id="dismissError">x</a>
            "Sorry to interrupt"
        </span>
        <div id="auraErrorMessage">CSS Error</div>
        <div id="auraErrorStack"></div>
        <div class="auraErrorFooter">
            <a href="?nocache=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.cs88.force.com%2Fcommunityhome%2Fs%2F" id="auraErrorReload">Refresh</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like some kind of network error, maybe it's not loading certain CSS files. But I honestly have no idea.
The component is sitting on a Community Builder page on a site.
I'm not getting anything on the debug logs for that logged in user.

EDIT: The above code is what I'm getting in the developer tools when trying to view the component.
I decided to work forensically and break down my code to the simplest forms possible, and see where it breaks:
Version 1 (displays `Random text`.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
access="global" controller="GSTAR_LGHT_CTRL">
    Random text
</aura:component>
```

Version 2 (displays `Random text`)

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
access="global" controller="GSTAR_LGHT_CTRL">
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem >
                Random text
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

Then I started noticing that adding in my inner components (instead of `Random text`) caused it to break.
After a lot of removing and replacing lines I've narrowed it down to two problematic lines:
1. `<aura:attribute name="list1" type="MyObject__c[]"/>` in the outermost component.
2. `<aura:attribute name="obj1" type="MyOtherObject__c"/>` in an inner component.
Commenting out both those lines lets everything render properly (just without the added functionality required by those attributes).
As an aside, with those lines in (and the component not rendering), the JS in the controller does not run (I'm not seeing output from my `init` functions in the `console.log`).

Comment: can you please share you original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was permissions the whole time.
Somehow over the weekend those two affected objects were set to `No Access` on the user profile viewing these components.
Resetting those to `Read` solved the problem.

> **For any future dev (myself included) looking for a solution to this problem.**
>   The `<div id="auraErrorMessage">CSS Error</div>` just means that the Salesforce compiler/parser that renders html from the lightning components choked very early on. There is no Javascript, there are no database calls, there is nothing because it checked that it had access to all objects and actually didn't.
>   Instead of throwing a helpful error message, or even saying something in the debug logs, it just throws up its hands and serves an empty page (within the Aura wrapper). The first we (the client) hear about it is when the browser tries to render a non-existent CSS class.
>   So if you are seeing this problem, check your object permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I changed the following session setting -

Go to **Setup** > **Session Settings** and disable "*Enable secure and persistented browser caching to improve performance*"

If this issue still persists then try the following solutions -

- Try a different browser.
- Clear cookies/cache.
- Try an incognito
  window.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. Disabled the setting, cleared browser cache and cookies, tried incognito and a different browser. Nothing.

Comment: Can you just put a random text and see if that's showing on the page? Also, make sure you are making the changes in the correct org and previewing in the same org?